# Is it lacking tzniuth to be a street musician as a male?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, music, stringency-chumrah, parnassah-livelihood

Is playing music in public as a Street musician in any way a lack in tzniuth. Are there different opinions on the matter?

Comment: Why do you think it's lacking in tzniut? Also, practical halacha questions are not for this site, but rather for your halachic authority.

Comment: Is there something that leads you to think that being a male would affect the answer?

Comment: When the Chazon Ish ztzl was urged to go on walks for his health he did so in the forest for the sake of tzniuth, and that would just be walking as compared to playing an instrument. More emphasis is put on a female to be tzniuth.

Comment: @CMS Talmide hakhamim are accustomed to a higher standard of צניעות (see H. Deoth 5:6). Presumably the Hazon Ish wore different clothes on his health walks than he understood to be normally befitting a talmid-hakham, and accordingly attempted to do so in a more discrete manner.

Comment: What about playing an instrument do you think would not be צניעות? Is it something specific to your type of instrument? Why is this question specific to street performance as opposed to any public performance?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya CMS and thanks for this first question. Your question might get closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?

Comment: @CMS are you worried about seeing not "tznius" images/people? Or is it the attraction you would gain that would make this not be tzanua?

Comment: Rashbam Bava Basra 110A https://www.sefaria.org/Rashbam_on_Bava_Batra.110a.5.3?with=all&lang=bi. 
אבל לעשות מלאכה להתפרנס אין כאן גנאי:

Comment: Try thinking of tzniut as a continuum. Sure this is less tzanua than living in a cave and more tzanua than being an underwear model. The hard question is more where to draw the line for each person in each context. Be very skeptical of anyone who thinks they know how to do that for everyone at the same time.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you